# Jquery - Is there a shorter way to get this attribute?

Tags: jquery

Here is the **jquery** I made to get the attribute:

```
var numeroBat = $(this).parents('td').children('h3').attr('name');
```

**HTML:**

```
<td><h3 name="b0">Title</h3>
<ul><li>THIS....
```

My command is pretty big, I'm sure there is a more beautiful, a shorter way?

Comment: What is `$(this)`? Where is your starting point?

Comment: with only above code, -> NO :D

Comment: If there is only one `h3` within the `td`, you can do `$(this).closest('h3').attr('name');`

Comment: @SaeedNeamati this is
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox0" name="cable"> 

and that is come right after the <li>, well i wrote it by THIS :)

Comment: @TamilVendhan - The h3 tag is not a parent of where "THIS" is located so your suggestion won't work.  `.closest()` only looks at parents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hereby my solution to the question above:

```
$("h3[name]").attr("name");
```

This will use the CSS Selector of jQuery to search for an element `h3` that has the attribute `name`. When it has found such a element you can, as stated in your own example, return the attribute value with `.attr("name");`

You can also prepend the "td" element which would get to the following example:

```
$("td h3[name]").attr("name");
```

Hopefully this is what you seek.

Comment: Woo nice ! Pretty nice & short ! Thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think this is about the shortest you can get:

```
var name = $(this).closest("td").children("h3:first").attr("name");
```

I changed it from what you have only slightly to make sure it's only selecting one parent "td" (the closest one) and one h3 child (the first one).

`.closest("td")` goes up the parent chain and finds the first `<td>` tag.  `.children("h3:first")` gets the first `<h3>` tag that's a child.

If you could assume that there was only one `<h3>` tag in the `<td>`, then you could do this:

```
var name = $(this).closest("td").find("h3").attr("name");
```

or this:

```
var name = $(this).closest("td").children("h3").attr("name");
```

The difference between `.find()` and `.children()` is that `.find()` will find an `<h3>` anywhere in the `<td>`, but `.children()` only looks at the direct children of the `<td>`.  One is more flexible if your markup changes a bit in the future, while the other is more strict about where to look.  It's up to you which is better.

Obviously, this is not much different than what you originally proposed, but there is no other way.  You have to have one operation to go up to find the appropriate parent, one to go down to find the `<h3>` and one to get the desired attribute.